# Determining if a letter in a list of letters is uppercase

Tags: python, loops

I am attempting to write a program where it takes a list input by the user and determines if the letter in the list is uppercase or not. This is the code I have so far.

```
#  Write a Python function to count how many letters in a string are in uppercase.

print("Hey, do you wanna see a cool trick I can do? I can count how many letters in a list of letters are uppercase!")
print("Here, I can prove it!")
print("Gimme a list of letters!")

letter = input("Enter a list of letters, seperating each by a comma. (put both uppercase and lowercase!) ")
letter_list = letter.split(",")
print("The list you gave was...")
print(letter_list)
print("And if we seperate those, we get...")
for letter in letter_list:
    print(letter)
    
print("Now, I'm going to count how many of those are uppercase!")
```

I am currently trying to get it to check if the letter is uppercase properly. I have tried an if statement nested in a for loop, but I'm unsure if I did it right, because it didn't work. The code I input was:

```
for letter in letter_list:
    if letter.isupper == True:
        capital = capital + 1
```

capital is what is being printed back to the user showing the amount of capital letters.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code has a few problems. The first is that you are not declaring `capital` before incrementing it. You should have `capital = 0` before the for a loop. Second, you are comparing with `==`, but you should use `is` instead. Lastly, to check if a letter is uppercase, you must call `letter.isupper()` (not `letter.isupper`). If you don't use parentheses, then it is referring to the function itself and you'll get all kinds of weird errors.

Here is the code that I got to work:

```
# ... rest of your code ...

capital = 0
for letter in letter_list:
    if letter.isupper() is True:
        capital = capital + 1
print("Number of capital letters: " + capital)
```

Comment: If this answer solved your question, then you can mark it ass correct.

Comment: *then you can mark it ass* made my day :D . Thanks for the smile it caused.

Comment: `is True` doesn't make much sense though.

Answer (score 0):

Since isupper is a string method, you need the () at the end of the method call.
So it would look like this

```
for letter in letter_list:
    if letter.isupper() == True:
        capital = capital + 1
```

Also, make sure you initialize capital before you start the for loop.

Answer (score 0):

As an suggestion or alternative solution, you can use Regex;

```python
import re

str = "Hey, do you wanna see a cool trick I can do? I can count how many letters in a list of letters are uppercase!"

r1 = re.findall(r"[A-Z]", str)
print(len(r1))
```